# Dual rail power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

In a computer PSU there are a few 12 V outputs. However it's not possible to connect one of them to ground and use that as a virtual ground to get both + and - 12 V to power dual rail ICs. My question is if this is can be achieved using two separate PSUs after of course checking that their respective grounds are not connected to earth.

There is already a -12 V output which is available already in the PSU has a max of 0.8 A which is less than my requirement.

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using something other than a computer PSU. Power supplies with bipolar outputs are readily available.

Comment: Try searching the web for [+12V -12V dual supply 5A](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%2B12V+-12V+dual+supply+5A&t=opera&ia=web) or similar.  What you suggest might be technically possible, or it might cause them both to fail - best to get something that you know will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Two ATX computer power supplies can't be used to generate a dual +/- 12V supply either. At least, not safely.

ATX computer supplies all have their black 0V common ground wires connected to metal case and the mains input protective earth wire, so it will be rather useless to check if you can find one that is not connected. So the grounds of two ATX supplies are already connected together via mains plug protective earth pins.

And no, for electrical safety and for proper operation of the power supplies, bypassing the mains earth or modifying the internals of ATX power supplies to disconnect mains earth from black 0V common ground wires is also generally **not** a good idea.

Comment: The OP asked if the two power supplies can be used to create +/-12V.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. better safe than sorry!

Comment: @user263983. To join two atx psus in order to get a beefier -12V rail requires one psu to be floated. This would require disconnecting the 0V from earth as explained in the answer.